# Can't run stock SF Container out of the box on local cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a stock out of the box VS2019 Azure Service Fabric Container app. It and every other Service Fabric app won't run on the local cluster. I get this:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: ServiceFabricContainer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Publish started: Project: ServiceFabricContainer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Started executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
2>Finished executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:00:00.5863836
-------- Package started: Project: ServiceFabricContainer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
ServiceFabricContainer -> C:\dev\ServiceFabricContainer\pkg\Debug
-------- Package: Project: ServiceFabricContainer succeeded, Time elapsed: 00:00:00.2741254 --------
2>Started executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
2>powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ". 'C:\dev\ServiceFabricContainer\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1' -ApplicationPackagePath 'C:\dev\ServiceFabricContainer\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'C:\dev\ServiceFabricContainer\PublishProfiles\Local.1Node.xml' -DeployOnly:$false -ApplicationParameter:@{} -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None' -OverwriteBehavior 'SameAppTypeAndVersion' -SkipPackageValidation:$false -ErrorAction Stop"
2>Copying application to image store...
2>Upload to Image Store succeeded
2>Registering application type...
2>Register application type started. Use Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType to query for status.
2>Running Image Builder process ...
2>Application package is registered.
2>Removing application package from image store...
2>Remove application package succeeded
2>Creating application...
2>New-ServiceFabricApplication : Repository Credentials for Account Name:sgentile cannot have a blank password if you 
2>have PasswordEncrypted set to True or Type set to Encrypted/SecretsStoreRef.
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
2>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:358 char:9
2>+         New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName $ApplicationNam ...
2>+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [New-ServiceFabr 
2>   icApplication], FabricException
2>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateApplicationInstanceErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.NewApplication
2> 
2>Finished executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:00:09.7611521
2>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in the error information. I just needed to have a non blank password. It works now.